# Why is the default exitcode -1

Tags: .net, compilation, development-environment

Not an issue but more of a curious question.

In visual Studio (and in some other applications ive come across) the default code posted by a program while exiting (i.e the "OK" of exitcodes) is -1,

Im curious as to why its just that, why not 0 which sounds more logical to me.

Does anyone have some deeper insight into why this is and the history behind it and why -1 is widley used as a default exitcode?

example:

> The program '[5208] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Ain‘t 0 the correct exit code when the Main-method returns void? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The default value for Environment.ExitCode is 0.  A good reason to see -1 back is stopping debugging intentionally.  In general any abnormal termination, unhandled exception for example, generates a non-zero value.